# Установка всех зависимостей maven-проекта

Tags: maven

Для ускорения CI требуется предустановить все зависимости мультимодульного maven-проекта в локальный репозиторий слейва. Для этого надо их как-то установить, а проект, теоретически, имеет право не собраться и провалиться на первом же модуле, из-за чего остальные не пройдут через процессинг. Как мне осуществить мою задачу?